# Google Chrome: Help page for desktop notifications screenshots need to be updated

Tags: feature-request, chat, faq-update-request

Help page for chat desktop notifications:
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/help/desktop-notifications

Those screenshots may need to be changed, as the entire process is *different* in the newer versions of **Chrome**. Menu labels, buttons are no longer the same, and users will have difficulty looking for the right button to click.

[image]

**UPDATE:** *I have taken and included the latest screenshots below.*

Answer (score 4):

I have taken and edited the screenshots using the latest version of Chrome, ready for SO team to use/implement them. Hope the circles are in good taste.

- Format: PNG-24
- Average file size: 30-40KB

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: [Not enough freehand](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/186983)! But seriously, nice work.

Comment: Nah, I think it has just amount of freehand for a FAQ. They're not designed for a Meta post. Them circles has *character* while still looking dignified.